# Client Side validation using jquery in MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-4.0

I am very new to ASP.NET 4 and MVC 4. I have a requirement of client-side validation using jQuery. Can some one please help me with a very basic code implementing of client side validation for example validating for an already registered username but can be customized for other validations too. What I exactly want it to have a method say TestForValidation() Defined Somewhere in My Project That compares the current supplied values in the form with the data already present in the database. I want this function to be called at the client side and the validation to be rendered at the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`[Remote]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) attribute. The documentation I've linked to contains a step-by-step guide on how to implement it.